# Send Tab Key to Telnet

Tags: c#, telnet, tcpclient

i am using below command to connect Telnet

```
    remote = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(remote);
    ns = client.GetStream();
```

using below command to send command to server.

```
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(command);
        ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

i am not able to send Tab Key to Telnet Client.

Please provide me solution.

Comment: Choose `c#` or `vb.net`. Don't add multiple languages like that..

Comment: `byte[] data = new[] { (byte)'\t' };` ?

Comment: Do you want C++ or VB.NET code?I don't understand this.

Comment: @Jedi question is in `C#`

Comment: I need in C#. i tried to convert '\t' like below

byte[] data = new[] { (byte)'\t' };
ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


but it's not working.